# Get index of element properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

For each `.furcLeft` I want to have its unique index, starting from number 1.
With the provided code the first `.furcLeft` has number 1, but the second `.furcLeft` has number 3, and the next `.furcLeft` restarts from 1. This is not supposed to happen, the index should continue but not restart.

```js
$(".furkation .bottom-addFurcation .furcLeft").each(function() {
   $(this).html(($(this).index()+1));
});
```

```html
<tr class="furkation">
  <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- Number 1 should appear here -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="divider"></div>
     
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
  </td>
  
  <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="divider"></div>
     
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 4 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
  </td>
<tr>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.each($(".furcLeft"), function(index, item) {
          $(item).html(index+1);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="furkation">
  <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- Number 1 should appear here -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="divider"></div>
     
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
  </td>
  
  <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="divider"></div>
     
     <div class="furcLeft"> <!-- 4 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
     </div>
  </td>
<tr>
```

Comment: @Majer Badawi Thank you! This works as I wanted to. Could you also give me a little explonation how this works?

Comment: @Alex check this doc: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(".furkation .furcLeft").each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).html(i + 1);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="furkation">
    <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
      <div class="furcLeft">
        <!-- Number 1 should appear here -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="furcLeft">
        <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="bottom-addFurcation">
      <div class="furcLeft">
        <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>

      <div class="furcLeft">
        <!-- 4 -->
        <div class="insert_furcation"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When using `.each()`, it is passed an Index and an Element. You can use this to label them if you choose.